# PHP codeigniter how to make array of variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter. I want to know how to create a array of variables. Besides demonstrated below.

```
$this->data['country'] = $country;
$this->data['state'] = $state;
$this->data['city'] = $city;
```

Comment: Well, you make an array, with variables. What's the context? What are you trying to do? Why doesn't the CI standard work for you?

Comment: do you mean an array of variables to pass from your controller to your view?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want a data array displayed inside a view, it should be something like this:

Controller:

```
$data['data_array'] = array(
             'country' => $country,
             'state'   => $state,
             'city'    => $city);
```

Pass it to view:

```
$this->load->view('your_view_name', $data);
```

In the view:

```
echo $data_array['country'];
```

I haven't tested it but something like that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array('country' => $country,
             'state'   => $state,
             'city'    => $city);

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: how to display this array ?

Comment: this arrya not working in codeigniter . you should use $this->data['data'] = array('country' => $country,
             'state'   => $state,
             'city'    => $city);

Comment: but i don't know to display this array.